# How do I filter data that are words?

Tags: r, dataframe

I apologize for the confusing phrasing of the question, but I wasn't quite sure how to state it. Essentially, I am trying to use the filter() function form the dplyr package in order to filter my data so that the remaining data fulfills a certain requirement. The column of data that I wish to filter the rest of the data by is non-numerical. How can I filter the data using this column?
The code I attempted to use is below:

`hplayer_1<-filter(brim, playerId="ff42baa6-89ef-11e6-8e45-a45e60e298d3")`

I apologize if this has already been asked.

Comment: Lets say your data set is `**brim**` you would say 

brim %>% filter(playerId == "ff42baa6-89ef-11e6-8e45-a45e60e298d3")

Comment: You probably just need to use `==` not `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to filter you have to use '=='.

Try:

```
hplayer_1 <- filter(brim, playerId == "ff42baa6-89ef-11e6-8e45-a45e60e298d3")
```